# Error con sentencia SQL preparada mediante PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Hasta ahora nunca había utilizado las sentencias preparadas pero por lo que he leído son necesarias a la hora de evitar inyección SQL como podría ocurrir, por ejemplo, desde un formulario web. Para probarlas he escrito el siguiente código:

Una función para conectarme a la base de datos:

```
function connectDB2(){
   $con = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "root", "eventos");
    if($con->connect_error){
       die("La conexión ha fallado, error número " . $con->connect_errno . ": " . $con->connect_error);
    }else{
       // echo 'Conexión establecida con éxito';
    }

    return $con;   
}
```

Otra función para dar de alta un nuevo evento en la base de datos mediante una consulta preparada:

```
function new_event($title,$color,$start){
    $conexion = connectDB2();
    mysqli_set_charset($conexion, "utf8"); //formato de datos utf8
    $conexion->prepare("INSERT INTO eventos(titulo,color,comienzo) VALUES(?,?,?)");
    $conexion->bind_param('sss',$title,$color,$start);
    $conexion->execute();
    $conexion->close();
}
```

Desde otro fichero PHP que incluye el fichero contenedor de las funciones anteriores, llamo a la función `new_event()` con los datos a insertar:

```
new_event("Evento de prueba 3","purple","2016-05-07");
```

PHP me devuelve el siguiente error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli::bind_param()
```

¿Qué puedo estar haciendo mal?

Comment: Solucionado, edito en la respuesta de abajo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solucionado, al parecer el objeto que llamaba a los métodos `prepare()` y `bind_param()` estaba mal instanciado. A continuación dejo la solución referente a mi código:

```
function new_event($title,$color,$start){
    $conexion = connectDB2();
    mysqli_set_charset($conexion, "utf8"); //formato de datos utf8
    $stmt = $conexion->prepare("INSERT INTO eventos(titulo,color,comienzo) VALUES(?,?,?)");
    $stmt->bind_param('sss',$title,$color,$start);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
    $conexion->close();
}
```

Comment: Hechi, me alegro que lo hayas solventado, no olvides en marcar cómo respuesta correcta.

Comment: Cuando pasen los dos días de rigor para aceptar mi propia respuesta la marcaré, gracias por el recordatorio.